# How to simplify or improve my code (or how to Flatten inside the matrix)?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, list-manipulation

I believe that it may be simplified, but I have no ideas anymore..
I need to flatten inside each element of array.
F.ex. {{1}, 128552, 6, 1} ---> {1, 128552, 6, 1}

Input data (Z - requests, t - periods of time):

```
Z = {{ 1,  3, 3, 7}, {8, 6, 6, 3}, {3, 5, 6, 13}, 
 {15, 15, 9, 4}, {1, 1, 3, 6}, {9, 4, 3,  2}}

t = {{129600, 30240}, {30240, 10080}, {10080, 1440}, {1440, 0}}
```

I need to generate time of each request, then number of product (1-6), then sort it and give the index number of requst and in the end append 1.

My decision:

```
MapIndexed[Prepend[Append[#, 1], #2] &, Sort[Flatten[Table[Partition[Append[Riffle[
RandomInteger[t[[i]], Z[[j, i]]], j], j], 2], {j, 6}, {i, 4}], 2], #1[[1]] > #2[[1]] &]]
```

It's part of the answer:

```
{{{1}, 128559, 3, 1}, {{2}, 128229, 6, 1}, {{3}, 127041, 4, 1},....,{{151}, 34, 3, 1}, {{152}, 18, 4, 1}}
```

I don't know how to simplify my decision..

Comment: Try `Flatten[{#2, #, 1}] &` instead of `Prepend[Append...]&` in the first argument of `MapIndexed`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of improvements for your code:

```
MapIndexed[
 Join[#2, #, {1}] &,
 SortBy[
  Flatten[
   Table[
    Thread@{RandomInteger[t[[i]], Z[[j, i]]], j}
    , {j, 6}, {i, 4}]
   , 2],
  -#[[1]] &]
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks again! This is much more simple than my code=)